# round corners with repeated background image in the same button android

Tags: android, button, background-image, rounded-corners, repeat

is there any way to have a background image in a button and corners of this button are rounded

because according all exampls I saw, the property in which we set a bakground image is the same in which we can set an xml file to make round corners

then is it possible to round up both in same button knowing that the image background must be repeated

here is my code to make round corner :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />    
    <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#B1BCBE" />
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <padding android:left="0dip" android:top="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:bottom="0dip" />
</shape>
```

and here is the code to have a background image repeated :

```
    <bitmap
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:src="@drawable/backtemplate"
android:tileMode="repeat"
android:dither="true" />
```

I want to round up those two file into one button to have a round corners button with repeated background image

Answer (score 0):

Try using the shape file on `android:background`, and your image on `android:src`. You then may have to use [Scale Type](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html).

Comment: I don't find android:src in button property

Comment: You'll have to use an [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html)

Comment: But if you use ImageButton then you have no support for text.